# Use of the Rename Command

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a two part question.

I have a series of files with the names "file.pdb.#", where # is an integer.

1.) How can I script to rename all the "file.pdb.#" to "file_#.pdb", where the integer is preserved? All files are in the same directory.

I presumably need to read in the constant string (file.pdb.) with the variable being the #.

2.) Even more important, how would I have searched for this answer, properly, among answered questions? I have no doubt this question has been answered many times before. However, I am not sure how I might have properly searched for the answer to this question (and obviously I should learn to search previously answered questions better to not bother people in the future). I cannot imagine what the right search string is (googling how to read in files and rename them in Linux is awfully generic and I waded through suggestions not germane to this sort of file format manipulation).

Comment: Your 2nd part needs to be a different question on meta; not on AU.  Please remove it and re-ask.

Comment: Answer for first question `mmv file.pdb.* file_#1.pdb`

Answer (score 7):

You can use *capture groups* and *backreferences* e.g.

```
rename -vn -- 's/\.(pdb)\.(\d+)/_$2.$1/' *.pdb.*
```

to match a literal period `\.` followed by (literal) string `pdb`, followed by a second period `\.` and then a sequence of one or more digits `\d+`, copying the string and digit sequence into numbered capture groups `$1` and `$2` respectively and then re-substituting them in reverse order with an underscore in place of the first period.

Options `-v` and `-n` are for verbose output (listing any changes made) and no-operation, allowing you to test the correctness before committing to making any actual substitutions: **you will need to remove the `n` option to actually apply the changes**.

The `--` marks the end of command options - this just makes the command more robust in the rare case that you have filenames that start with a hyphen.

---

Testing it in a directory containing files `file.pdb.1 file.pdb.2 file.pdb.3 file.pdb.4 file.pdb.5` (among others):

```
$ rename -vn -- 's/\.(pdb)\.(\d+)/_$2.$1/' *.pdb.*
file.pdb.1 renamed as file_1.pdb
file.pdb.2 renamed as file_2.pdb
file.pdb.3 renamed as file_3.pdb
file.pdb.4 renamed as file_4.pdb
file.pdb.5 renamed as file_5.pdb
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the syntax a bit? The string did not work, when blindly copy/pasting it, such that there is a flaw in how I explained things that this did not work. I would like to understand what this says better.

Comment: @RobertMolt please see updated answer

Comment: I appreciate your efforts very much. There still seems to be a flaw; when implemented, with or without the n flag, there is no output. If you were to make two files in a directory named file.pdb.1 and file.pdb.2, and implemented the above, do you see the desired results?
You have explained everything beautifully, and I appreciate it. I assume *.pdb.* at the end simply clarifies on what set of files one should implement the aforementioned substitution.

Comment: @RobertMolt sorry I don't understand why it is not working for you: I have edited my answer to include the result of testing on my own system.

Comment: I appreciate your sincere efforts; clearly it works for you. Is the command shell-dependent? I am using bash. I am desperately reaching here trying to understand why this is not recognizing any of my files with the same names are causing this. I am running this on Red Hat linux, but I cannot imagine this should matter (I personally own a Ubuntu OS, but am doing this on a Red Hat flavor).

Comment: @RobertMolt if you are using RedHat, then AskUbuntu was not the right place for your question: it is possible that your system has a different `rename` command altogether - see [find/rename command doesn't work](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78645/65304)

Answer (score 1):

The strictest way possible, so that only filenames starting with `file.pdb.` followed by at least a digit will be renamed, using `rename`:

```
rename -n 's/(file)(\.pdb)\.([0-9]+)/$1_$3$2/' *
```

If the result is the expected one, remove the `-n` option:

```
rename 's/(file)(\.pdb)\.([0-9]+)/$1_$3$2/' *
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from excellent `rename` answers you have received already, you can use `bash` parameter expansion:

```
for i in *.pdb.*; do mv -i "$i" "${i%%.pdb.*}_${i##*.}.pdb"; done
```

- The pattern `${i%%.pdb*}` will get the `file` portion of name `file.pdb.#`
- `${i##*.}` will get the digits after `.pdb.`

Comment: Thank you, this suggestion worked (whereas the others did not for some reason). I was hoping to ask a bit more to understand it properly.

-i seems like an implicit variable which is a string

-"${i%%.pdb.*}  how is %% specifying the file portion? can you direct me to where I can understand why this syntax is grabbing the file name preceding .pdb?

-what is the underscore doing?

-how does ## read in the correct digits?

I tend to think of things in Fortran, my only real programming experience, and hence I am confused.

Comment: @RobertMolt i have taken the variables as variable `i`, then renamed them by using parameter expansion..its a feature of `bash` that will allow you to manipulate variables to get your desired portion (and many more operations)..i am afraid to get a full grasp off of it you need to get some idea about it first....you can read [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)..check out the `${parameter##word}` and `${parameter%%word}` portions